# How to make JS modal content accessible by URL?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

So, I apologize in advance if I misuse terms here. The TLDR version is that I maintain a wordpress site that I didn't build. The site is javascript heavy and includes a lot of content in modals created with the the Tingle Modal library. The site is designed as a single-column site, with hash based navigation to take users up and down the page. What I would like to achieve, is to make the modal content accessible by url, so that external users to be directed to the content. I think this is achievable with hash-based js navigation, but I'm not sure. This is complicated somewhat, since the Modals are generated by JS and PHP, and not just pulling out content buried in the html or hidden somewhere by CSS.

I assume to make this work I would need some sort of custom URL handler, that would call the modal function on submission (which wouldn't collide with the existing hash based nav), but that's about as far as I've thought this through. Any ideas on how to implement something like this?

Comment: This is a profound and important problem, however I am afraid that you won't find a complete answer on a Q&A site.

Comment: Appreciate the support and upvote, do you think I'm at least barking up the right tree?

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location and use `window.location.hash` from each page to get the URL fragment from the hash-based js navigation. Additionally use the event `onhashchange`(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange) to catch hash changes because they usually don't result in a page reload. Perhaps google for a hash-based js navigation library. Your problem is more how to interface the legacy Wordpress site to the new hash-based navigation which can be very difficult based on what people did before you.